# customize mocha-bamboo-reporter to include test file name

Tags: protractor, mocha.js, bamboo

I am trying to customize `mocha-bamboo-reporter` https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-bamboo-reporter, in my protractor tests,  to include a field named `file`, which includes the test file name in bamboo reports.

mocha-bamboo-reporter

```
  var o = {
      title: test.title
    , fullTitle: test.fullTitle()
    , duration: test.duration
    , file: test.file    // this is the new change  
  };
```

When i run the tests locally the generated `mocha.json` includes the `file` info that i want.

mocha.json

```
  {
      "title": "should show login form",
      "fullTitle": " Home Page should show login form",
      "duration": 300,
      "file": "xxx/tests/directory-name/test.js"
    },
```

In Bamboo I have a `Mocha Test Parser` build task for `mocha.json`, but in the bamboo reports `file` is never included, only `title`, `fullTitle`, `duration` etc. What do i need to do to get this info to show? Do i need to include something in `mochaBambooReporterReporterOptions`?

Bamboo Build Task

[image]

Comment: does your `mocha.json` is created in root directory. The problem may be because of the path to mocha.json

Comment: Its created in a directory `/reports`. I dont think thats the issue, as all other existing fields in mocha.json show in bamboo UI eg: `title`, `fullTitle`, `duration`, its only the new field `file` that I added, that does not show..